# Zen Cart PayPal Pro not staying on site

Tags: paypal, zen-cart

We have installed and properly configured Paypal Express checkout and it works fine.

We then installed PayPal Payments Pro (USA) and we can not get the system to work through the api. Everytime we click confirm order it takes us to paypals website rather than processing the order onsite.

What could be causing this issue.

PayPal Payments PRO DETAILS

```
Enable this Payment Module
True
Sort order of display.
1
Payment Zone
--none--
Set Order Status
Processing [2]
Set Unpaid Order Status
Pending [1]
Set Refund Order Status
Pending [1]
Payment Action
Final Sale
Transaction Currency
Only USD
Merchant Country
USA
Fraud Mgmt Filters - FMF
No
Live or Sandbox
live
Debug Mode
Off
```

EXPRESS CHECKOUT DETAILS

```
Enable this Payment Module
True
Sort order of display.
10
Payment Zone
--none--
Express Checkout Shortcut Button
Off
Set Order Status
Processing [2]
Set Unpaid Order Status
Pending [1]
Set Refund Order Status
Pending [1]
Express Checkout: Require Confirmed Address
No
Express Checkout: Select Cheapest Shipping Automatically
Yes
Express Checkout: Skip Payment Page
Yes
Express Checkout: Automatic Account Creation
Yes
Payment Action
Final Sale
Transaction Currency
Only USD
Store (Brand) Name at PayPal

Allow eCheck?
Instant Only
PayPal Page Style
Primary
API Signature -- Username
****************
API Signature -- Password
****************
API Signature -- Signature Code
****************
PayPal Mode
PayPal
Live or Sandbox
live
Debug Mode
Off
```

Debug Email

```
(live transaction) --> https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
Request Headers:
Array
(
    [0] => Content-Type: text/namevalue
    [1] => X-VPS-Timeout: 90
    [2] => X-VPS-VIT-Client-Type: PHP/cURL
    [3] => X-VPS-VIT-Integration-Product: PHP::Zen Cart(R) - PayPal/NVP
    [4] => X-VPS-VIT-Integration-Version: 1.5.1
)


Request Parameters: {SetExpressCheckout}
Array
(
    [AMT] => 10.00
    [ITEMAMT] => 10.00
    [L_NUMBER0] => GIFT 010
    [L_NAME0] => Gift Certificate $ 10.00 [29]
    [L_QTY0] => 1
    [L_AMT0] => 10.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [LOCALECODE] => US
    [ALLOWEDPAYMENTMETHOD] => InstantPaymentOnly
    [GIFTMESSAGEENABLE] => 0
    [GIFTRECEIPTEENABLE] => 0
    [GIFTWRAPENABLE] => 0
    [GIFTWRAPNAME] =>
    [GIFTWRAPAMOUNT] => 0
    [BUYEREMAILOPTINENABLE] => 0
    [CUSTOMERSERVICENUMBER] =>
    [BRANDNAME] => Elite Specialty Meats
    [PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
    [ALLOWNOTE] => 1
    [LANDINGPAGE] => Billing
    [NOSHIPPING] => 1
    [EMAIL] => info@website.com
    [SHIPTOPHONENUM] => 7159522602
    [RETURNURL] =>
https://www.website.org/ipn_main_handler.php?type=ec
    [CANCELURL] =>
https://www.website.org/index.php?main_page=checkout_shipping&ec_cancel=1
    [PAGESTYLE] => Primary
    [METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
    [USER] => ******************
    [PWD] => ****************
    [VERSION] => 61.0
    [SIGNATURE] => ********************************************************
)


Response:
Array
(
    [TOKEN] => EC-3GP63978AS457874S
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2012-11-03T21:48:19Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 6d65cddaebe3
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 61.0
    [BUILD] => 4181146
    [CURL_ERRORS] =>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You posted a log file which shows that your site is running SetExpressCheckout, which means your customer is choosing "Pay by PayPal" via Express Checkout, which will indeed take them offsite to PayPal's site to login and select funding options.

If you were doing a Pro transaction (filling in Credit Card details on your own site), it would not trigger a SetExpressCheckout call.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is likely because you did not edit the settings in the PP Express module. You must select Payflow instead of Express Checkout from the express module. You do need both the express and pro modules installed, but oddly, the setting that keeps them on your site is found in the express module.